# how to give hover effect in tr when we use tr:odd

Tags: jquery, html

I am using tr:odd selector to give table>tr odd color, I also want tr hover effect, its work fine in normal tr but that color does not appear in tr:odd

you will get code here : http://jsfiddle.net/MygAx/

Thanks in advance

Comment: its already having hover effect and color changes on hover. what is that you want exactly.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the css you are setting by script is considered to be inline which has higher priority than the one set by external css file.

You can do this to solve the problem:

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("tr:odd").addClass("odd")
});
```

**CSS**

```
tr.odd{background-color: #eee}
tr:hover{ background:#ccc}
```

Remember, the order in the css is important.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is not to use jQuery for this.

Instead, you should use the standard CSS selector `nth-of-type` to achieve this.

You can then override it easily with the `:hover` selector that you already have.

```
tr:nth-of-type(2n) {background:#eee;}
tr:hover{ background:#ccc}​
```

With this CSS, and with the JS removed, your existing JSFiddle code works exactly as you'd like it.

You can even combine them so that odd rows get a different hover colour to even rows.

The only problem you'll have with this is with old versions of IE, which don't support `nth-of-type`, but there are hacks that can work around this. ([IE9.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) or [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/))

The reason it didn't work with the jQuery version is because when jQuery sets its CSS, the browser sees it as being inline in the HTML code, and thus takes higher priority than plain CSS code.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes I used before tr:nth-of-type(2n) but its dose not work in IE8 and  client wants that it has to  work fine in IE8, that is the only reason we use jquery.

Comment: did you check the IE9.js or Selectivzr options?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `!important`:

```
tr:hover{ background:#ccc !important}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MygAx/2/)

`css()` method adds a style attribute to the elements, properties in style attribute override other properties, in order to avoid using `!important` you can use a class instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("tr:odd").addClass('grey')
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MygAx/6/)

Comment: yes I almost forget about that !important tag..:-) yes its works fine now. Thank you

Comment: @user1479316 - using `!important` should always be considered a last resort; there are better solutions than this.

Comment: @user1479316 you are welcome, using `!important` is not recommended alternatively you can use `addClass` instead.

Answer (score 0):

see actually what happen first you apply hover event and you reassign other CSS (its is not second class so) element will be replaced with second CSS

http://jsfiddle.net/MygAx/7/